# Match beginning of words in Mysql for UTF8 strings

Tags: mysql, regex

I m trying to match beignning of words in a mysql column that stores strings as varchar. Unfortunately, REGEXP does not seem to work for UTF-8 strings as mentioned [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

So,

> `select * from names where name REGEXP '[[:<:]]Aandre';`

does not work if I have name like Foobar Aándreas

However,

> select * from names where name like '%andre%'

matches the row I need but does not guarantee beginning of words matches.

Is it better to do the like and filter it out on the application side ? Any other solutions?

Comment: I ended up doing this on the app side (Java in my case). I used like '%foo%' for the db query and then, pattern matched the results by removing 'diacritical marks' using java.text.Normalizer and matching on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from names where name like 'andre%'
```

Answer (score 0):

A citation from tha page you mentioned:

> **Warning**
>
> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from names where name like 'andre%'` is not solution for eg:

name = 'richard andrew', because the string begining with richa... and not with andre...

for the moment, the temporaly solution, for search words (words != string) starting with a string

```
select * from names where name REGEXP '[[:<:]]andre';
```

But it no matching with accented words, eg: ándrew.

Any other solution, with regular expressions (mysql) to search in **accented words**?